# How to have 20-30TB space with many 2TB HDDs?

Tags: disk-space-utilization, hard-drive, storage

I want to build a server with a minimum of 20TB - 30TB space. I want to make a single server with many 2TB HDDs. How is it possible to have 20TB-30TB for a single folder ie. */var/www* which will contain my server files. It is a web server.

Comment: any requirements for RAID?

Comment: @ColdT I didn't know what was RAID .... After reading the answers and googling about it, I came to know about it! Yes I will use RAID!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technology you are looking for is called RAID (Redundant Array of Independent/Inexpensive Disks). You can create a disk array on a number of levels.

- Hardware controller (LSI Logic etc) or integrated storage (Drobo etc)
- Software on the driver level like Dynamic Disks (windows), mdraid (Linux/MacOS)
- Software on the volume or filesystem level like ZFS, Logical volume managers (LVM)

Any of these might be suitable for a web server, exact configuration depending on requirements.

I'll add that 4 TB drives have just started appearing, which could significantly lower the cost of a 20-30 TB array.

Comment: thanks for pointing that 4TB HDD are there .... I really didn't know about it .... my cost will also be reduced!

Answer (score 3):

The magic Keyword in this case is **[Logical Volume Manager (short LVM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_%28Linux%29)**.
With this you can create volumes, and attach harddrives to this volume.
Then you can mount this volume on /var/wwww

It is possible to use this **[LVM with RAID system in Combination](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-software-raid1-on-a-running-lvm-system-incl-grub2-configuration-debian-squeeze)**. So you can push speed or data-security(in case one drive breaks down). And i would reccomend you to use RAID 5 or [RAID 6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels#RAID_6) if you have that many drives.
Otherwise if one drive brokes down you might take it out of your lvm but you would leave a hole in you filesystem. And this will bring you in stressy troubles.

I used to spend nearly to weeks to understand lvm, Raid and to set up a testing environment.
But it's worth. It's like juggleing with data.

Comment: Based on general recommendations, there are too many drives to recommend RAID 5 or 6. Should consider RAID 5+0 or 6+0 instead. Manageable rebuild times points towards RAID 6+0. Similarly, due to the number of disks, the risk of running a JBOD (the typical concatenated LVM configuration) will be very high, and likely can not be recommended.

Comment: Good opinion Roy! Sounds quite right!